# Meaning of ",$d" in replacement part of sed command

Tags: sed

I came across this command in a project I am working on:

`sed -i '/regex/,$d' file`

I don't understand how the `,$d` part works.  If I omit any part of `,$d` I get errors.  In my tests it looks like it replaces the matching line and anything after it with nothing. Example:

File with contents:

```
first line 
second line regex
third line
fourth line
```

Comes out as after running that command:

```
first line
```

I couldn't find any documentation in the man page that explains this, though I could have easily missed it.  The man page is hard for me to parse...

This is example was tested with `GNU Sed v 4.2.2`.

Comment: Check out http://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html for a good tutorial. Good luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a replacement command; the `sed` *substitute* or *replace* command looks like `s/from/to/`.

The general form of a `sed` script is a sequence of commands - typically a single letter, but some of them take arguments, like the `s` command above - with an optional address expression before each. You are looking at a `d` *(delete line)* command preceded by the address expression `/regex/,$`

The address range specifies lines from the first regex match through to the end of the file (`$` in this context specifies the last line) and the action `d` deletes the specified lines.

Although many people only ever encounter simple `sed` scripts which use just the `s` command, this behavior will be described in any basic introduction to `sed`, as well as in the man page.

Comment: Ahh, ok I see. Thanks for the clarification. I was able to find the documentation in the man page with your explanation.

Comment: The man page is admittedly a tough read if it's your first exposure to `sed`; it is a reference, not a tutorial.